# Unexpected NULLs

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find out how many items where confirmed from an purchase order database.

The database contains "yes" or "no" which needs to be converted to numbers so I can see the total number of items that were confirmed or not.

The data types are `varchar2`. There should be no NULLs in the *R2* column and *R3* should not equal the RESPONSE_COUNT. I am using ITEMID to add the total responses of each item.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Query:

```
SELECT 
POSITION_NAME,
ORDER_NAME,
COUNT(SELECT RESPONSESTRING FROM ORDER_CONFIRM WHERE (RESPONSESTRING = RESPONSESTRING) AND (RESPONSESTRING LIKE 'NO')) AS R2, -- converting the string "no" to a number
COUNT(SELECT RESPONSESTRING FROM ORDER_CONFIRM WHERE (RESPONSESTRING = RESPONSESTRING) AND (RESPONSESTRING LIKE 'YES')) AS R3, -- converting the string "yes" to a number
TO_NUMBER(COUNT(DISTINCT ITEMID)) AS RESPONSE_COUNT
FROM ORDER_CONFIRM
WHERE ORDER_NAME LIKE 'XX.XX.MMYY'
AND RESPONSESTRING IS NOT NULL
HAVING TO_NUMBER(COUNT(DISTINCT ITEMID)) >= '5'
GROUP BY
POSITION_NAME,
ORDER_NAME
ORDER BY POSITION_NAME DESC;

Result:

POSITION_NAME | ORDER_NAME | R2 | R3 | RESPONSE_COUNT
======================================================
POSITION A    | XX.XX.MMYY | (null) | 5 | 5 
POSITION B    | XX.XX.MMYY | (null) | 5 | 5 
POSITION C    | XX.XX.MMYY | (null) | 8 | 8
POSITION D    | XX.XX.MMYY | (null) | 10 | 10
```

Comment: If the values are YES or NO, why do you use `LIKE`? Also, `RESPONSESTRING = RESPONSESTRING` won't work right. You have to use the proper table names or aliases, otherwise you are just comparing a value to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have strange conversion to number (is there some reason for using subselect?)
Hope you may just use 
`SUM(DECODE(RESPONSESTRING,'NO',1,0)) AS R2,` - to count 'NO'-s
`SUM(DECODE(RESPONSESTRING,'YES',1,0)) AS R3,` - to count 'YES'-s
In such case you will not get 'NULL'

Comment: After making the change, l'm not getting NULL anymore, but now I'm getting '0' for both yes and no.

Comment: Could you please post content of your order_confirm table, and query that you get after modification. Both 0 means that column RESPONSESTRING doesn't contain neither 'YES' nor 'NO'; or that query contain some mistake.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: After doing some more investigation of the database, I came across another path to gain the results I was looking for using CASE. I've only been working with the database for about a week now so I don't completely understand the details yet.